# Accessing local postgres database via internet

Tags: java, database, postgresql, web-services

I have a pos software which is developed with `java` and it is running perfectly on `localhost` with a `PostgreSQL` database. But the problem is my client wants to use the pos software while he is travelling.

So my problem is how to access the `PostgreSQL database` which is running on `localhost` via internet. I searched this on google and found that I can use `web services` to connect to my `PostgreSQL database` via `internet`. But don't know how to access those `web services` via `internet` because I don't have an static IP address.

Can anyone please tell me:

- What is the best way to access my `localhost PostgreSQL database` via `internet`?
- If the best way is using `web services` how to access those services via internet if I don't have an `static` IP address?

I'm using `java` to develop my desktop POS software and it is running on a windows computer.

Comment: You surely use JDBC to access the DB. Nothing prevents you to use JDBC over a public network. Though you should take care to encrypt the connection. If you do not have a static IP then it is time to get one. Dynamic DNS services might help in the meantime.

Comment: I've done it using WS before. I simply built several services which would do what the customer needed and made them available on the internet. Regarding how to make your localhost server acessible via internet, you have to do some port forwarding on your router which shouldn't be very difficult, but it is not related to coding. Keep in mind though without a static ip address, you will have to use some Dynamic DNS service like No-Ip.

Answer (score 0):

You would have the same trouble that accessing a box running PostgreSQL: you need to locate that box somehow; it will happens if you deploy your Web Services and it is happening now that you want to access your database. There are many ways to achieve that, but basically you need a permanent connection to the Internet (of course) and a static (real) IP.

I would recommend you to deploy your application in [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/), [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/), or [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), to name a few.